# Symmetry non integrable Hamiltonian system

Tags: geometry, dynamical-systems, symmetry, hamilton-equations

We are in in open subset of $\mathbb{R}^6$ where the local coordinates
are $(q,p)$ where $q=(x,\theta_1,\theta_2)$ is the state and the costate is 
$p=(p_1,p_2,p_3)$.
We consider an Hamiltonian system and I compute 
numerically $2\pi$-periodic in time trajectories with respect to $(\theta_1,\theta_2)$, the others components are not necessarily periodic.

Projections on the plane $(\theta_1,\theta_2)$ are represented in figure below.
I would like to prove the symmetry on the $(\theta_1,\theta_2)$ plane.
 I should prove that (cf the manuscript figure) :
$A(t)=(\theta_1(t),\theta_2(t)),\; t\in[0,2\pi]$ 
is related with $C(t)=(2(x(t)-\theta_1(t))+\theta_1(t),2(\pi-x(t) -\theta_2(t))+\theta_2(t))$ by

$$
A(2\pi-t) = C(t)
$$

But problem : the Hamitnoian system is not integrable and I can't have 
explicit solutions...

Is there exists tehcniques to prove this (like Noether theorem but in the projective case)

[image: 1 parameter family of projection of periodic trajectories]

[image: caracterisation symmetry]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The projected orbits indeed seem to be reflexive symmetric in the line $\theta_2 = \pi - \theta_1$. The reflection in the line $\theta_2 = \pi-\theta_1$ is given by
\begin{equation}
 R: (\theta_1,\theta_2) \mapsto (\pi-\theta_1,\pi-\theta_2).
\end{equation}
However, if the *orbit* is symmetric, it doesn't mean that the *solution* is symmetric. In particular (assuming your system is nondegenerate), the direction of the flow reverses when you apply the reflection. So, a good way to test the symmetry is to see if the Hamiltonian system is *invariant* under simultaneous application of $R$ and time reversal. In other words, applying $R$ should have the same effect as reversing time, at least on the $\theta$-variables.

To be more concrete, let's look at the Hamiltonian system. We have
\begin{align}
 \frac{\text{d} \theta_{1,2}}{\text{d} t} &= \frac{\partial H}{\partial p_{2,3}},\tag{1}\\
 \frac{\text{d} p_{2,3}}{\text{d} t} &= -\frac{\partial H}{\partial \theta_{1,2}}.\tag{2}
\end{align}
Applying $R$ and time reversal to $\frac{\text{d} \theta_{1,2}}{\text{d} t}$ (in whatever order) leaves the left hand side of $(1)$ invariant. So, we obtain the requirement that $ \frac{\partial H}{\partial p_{2,3}}$ must be invariant with respect to those operations as well. Assuming your Hamiltonian $H$ is time-independent, this means that
\begin{equation}
  \frac{\partial H}{\partial p_{2,3}}(\theta_1,\theta_2) = \frac{\partial H}{\partial p_{2,3}}(\pi-\theta_1,\pi-\theta_2).
\end{equation}
Applying $t \mapsto -t$ to the left hand side of $(2)$ yields $-\frac{\text{d} p_{2,3}}{\text{d} t}$; therefore, we obtain a second condition
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial H}{\partial \theta_{1,2}}(\theta_1,\theta_2) = -\frac{\partial H}{\partial \theta_{1,2}}(\pi-\theta_1,\pi-\theta_2).
\end{equation}
An example of an Hamiltonian obeying these conditions is
\begin{equation}
H = \frac{1}{2}(p_2^2+p_3^2) + \cos(\theta_1) + \cos(\theta_2).
\end{equation}

Note that I didn't do anything with $x$ or $p_1$. Keep in mind that the reflection $R$ might *not* leave $x$-values invariant; however, since you're projecting onto the $(\theta_1,\theta_2)$-plane anyway, this isn't relevant (but important to realise!).

Comment: The reflection is $R(\theta_1,\theta_2)=(\pi-\theta_2,\pi-\theta_1)$ but I got the approach, many thanks ;)

Comment: You're absolutely right, sorry about that! :-)